# How do I stop Add-PnPFile overwriting files in Sharepoint

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

I have written a powershell script that loads files into our Sharepoint Online implementation using Add-PnPFile. The problem I've found if the file has the same physical name, even if the physical location of the file is different Sharepoint seems to think it's the same file and will overwrite the earlier ones with the later ones. For example :
[redacted]\6 Staff Records\CSA Performance Reviews\zzSP Testing - Johnny Depp\Performance\Call Reviews (1).docx
[redacted]\6 Staff Records\CSA Performance Reviews\zzPS Testing - Angelina Jolie\Performance\Call Reviews (1).docx

The latter file when uploaded using Add-PnPFile will overwrite the former even if the metadata is completely different.
I have temporarily overcome this by generating a timestamp value and adding to the filename as below ($values is an array of metadata values) :

```
$ActualLocation="[redacted]\6 Staff Records\CSA Performance Reviews\zzPS Testing - Angelina Jolie\Performance\Call Reviews (1).docx"
$NewFileName="Call Reviews (1) (62499159).docx"
add-pnpfile -Path $ActualLocation -NewFileName $NewFileName -Folder  $_doclibName -Values $values
```

A messy solution though. Is there anything I can use with Add-PnPFile that will tell Sharepoint that it is being sent unique files?

Answer (score 0):

According to my research and testing, you can avoid `Add-PnPFile` overwriting files by adding `-NewFileName xxxx`, for example:

```
Add-PnPFile -Path "E:\New\PnPPowershell.docx" -Folder "Shared Documents" -NewFileName "NewPnPPowershell.docx"
```

My test result:

[image]

More information for reference: [Add-PnPFile](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Add-PnPFile.html)

Comment: I am checking to see if the problem has been resolved .If you have any questions or progress, you can contact me in time.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I did use -NewFileName

Comment: CBC did you use a new unique filename?